# how to print previous 30 days from a date in python and the same in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar, tkcalendar

I am using Tkinter to build a Corona Travel History Questionnaire.

The front end has options to select a particular date - " D-Day Cronoa Confirmed".
Once the D-day is confirmed, the program is supposed to give fields for entering data on travel history.

I am using tkcalendar module in Python.

Problem: How to print the previous 30 days from a given date in python?

Question: Can we do anything in tkcalendar to print the last 30 days from a selected date in the window itself?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module you can find the last thirty days from any given date.

For example, the code:

```
first_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(30)
```

will give you the start period of this 30-day window. From there you simply need to fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

datetime and timedelta are made for this.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta                                                                                                                                                            

start = datetime(2020, 1, 1)                                                                                                                                                                        

for day in range(1, 31): 
   print(start-timedelta(days=day))
```